# Fourier analysis problem

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis

I'm learning Fourier analysis by Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi and got stuck on the step in problem 3 on page 213.
[image]

Here is my attempt:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
\sum _{j=1}^{d}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} v_{j} \ =\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}\\
...\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{d}}
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \hat{n} \ \leqslant \left| \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}\\
...\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{d}}
\end{bmatrix}\right| \\
=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}^{2}\sum _{j=1}^{d}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \leqslant ?\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}^{2} +\sum _{j=1}^{d}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}^{2}\right)
\end{array}$$
And I suppose I can simplify it that way, since I don't see any connection between inequality and derivatives (by the way, is that correct? I think the fact that u(x,t) is a solution to the wave equation can do the job, but I can't figure out how to).
$$\left( x_{d+1}^{2}\sum _{j=1}^{d} x{_{j}}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \leqslant ?\frac{1}{2}\left( x_{d+1}^{2} +\sum _{j=1}^{d} x{_{j}}^{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think, I figured it out, maybe it will be helpful for someone:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
\left( x_{d+1}^{2}\sum _{j=1}^{d} x{_{j}}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \leqslant ?\frac{1}{2}\left( x_{d+1}^{2} +\sum _{j=1}^{d} x{_{j}}^{2}\right)\\
( ab)^{1/2} \leqslant ?\frac{1}{2}( a+b)\\
2ab\leqslant \left( a^{2} +b^{2}\right) \ -\ which\ is\ a\ known\ result\ 
\end{array}$$